# customize spark csv line terminator

Tags: pyspark, export-to-csv, databricks

I am using pyspark code to generate csv from a dataframe using below code,

```
df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("header","true").mode("overwrite").save("/user/test")
```

But, when i open and see the line terminator in notepad++, it is coming with default line terminator "\n". I have tried different options such as textinputformat record delimiter set etc. but no luck. Is there a way to customize this EOL while exporting dataframe to csv in spark. Actually i need to customize this EOL with CRLF ("\r\n").Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I went with default line terminator. @Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lineSep` option to set a single character as line separator.

```py
(
 df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
 .option("header", "true")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("lineSep", "^")
 .save("/user/test")
)
```

Docs source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option